# How to use multi label while training multi label classification

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, multilabel-classification, resnet, densenet

I have a data set that consists of images. I am trying to perform multi-label classification on this data set. But the training labels consist of too many labels which are CSV file format. Now I find it a little difficult on how to utilizes these labels in CSV file during the course of training. I read some blogs; the author suggested performing one-hot encoding on these labels. Now I am stuck on how to proceed. Below is the screenshot of the label.

[image: screen shot]